# Tomcat or JBoss?

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, jboss, webserver

This question has repeated many times. May be i am a maniac but desperately want just a simple suggestion with solid reason.
I want to use Server for my spring based web project. i am messing up between two scenarios.

**Scenario #1-** I have a project which is web centric, so i should use Tomcat(My current scenario).

**Scenario #2-** what if i later have to use "JMS messaging for asynchronous integration" or "Web Services engine (JAX-WS and/or JAX-RS)" etc.

1. **Taking first point in mind, what if i go with JBOSS..??**
2. **Taking second point in mind, what if i were using Tomcat??**
3. **is it easy to later shift from Tomcat to JBoss or vice versa..??**

**NOTE:** I have zero experience with Jboss.

Please bear me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all JBoss AS is [based on JBoss web](http://jbossweb.jboss.org/) for which the core functionality is [provided by Tomcat](http://jbossweb.jboss.org/arch.html). So the right comparsion should be JBoss Web vs Tomcat.

[JBoss AS] is a full fledged application server complying to Java EE6 Web Profile and with many modules. The JBoss AS 7 standalone configuration directory [//standalone/configuration] has 3 configurations available to use such as standalone.xml which is supposed to be a typical configuration, standalone-full.xml which enables all modules and a standalone-ha.xml which is for High availability. JBoss AS also supports a domain mode which makes multiple servers manageable from a single interface. So if you are looking for a high availability(optional) enterprise class solution, go with JBoss AS.

If you are not using EJB, your webapp can easily can easily run on Tomcat for that. Since you are planning to use Spring, I presume you will be using Spring to manage the lifecycle of components. So that means you will not use JBoss for lifecycle management. Also JAX-RS libraries like Resteasy have spring integration so you will interact with these libraries via Spring. The same thing applies for JAX-WS libraries as well.

I have seen several projects support both of them. The right comparison should be JBoss AS vs [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out :-) I will definitely go with Apache Tomcat.